# Python considers sequence of integers as Date/Time data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read a file in Pyspark (Apache Spark with Python).
File content for example:

```
13,13,25
13,13,125
13,25,25
13,25,37
13,25,41
13,25,66
13,25,71
13,25,73
13,25,84
13,25,116
...
```

I would like to create dictionary of these sequences like:

```
{(13,13,25):0, (13,25,37):1, (13,25,41):2, (13,25,66):3, ..... }
```

Here are my attempts:

1) First I only tried to read the file line by line

```
textFile = sc.textFile(file)
feat_map = textFile.map(lambda line: line)
print(feat_map.take(10))
```

output is (it considers sequence of numbers as date/time):

```
[u'-------------------------------------------', u'Time: 2015-08-04 14:32:41', u'13,25,66', u'13,25,71', u'13,25,73', u'13,25,84', u'13,25,116']
```

2) In other attempt I tried to separate the individual numbers to fulfill the task:

```
textFile = sc.textFile(file)
feat_map = textFile.map(lambda line: line.split(','))\
                        .map(lambda word: (int(word[0]), int(word[1]), int(word[2])))\
                        .zipWithIndex().collectAsMap()
print(feat_map)
```

I got the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-------------------------------------------'
```

I also tried `int(float(word[x]))` but it's also not working.

How can I parse my file to generate dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your first line has the value

```
-------------------------------------------
```

Which cannot be correctly split and converted to ints. presumably this is a header row or something similar? You need to filter out this row.

Comment: no there is no such line or header row. First line is `13,13,25`. It is converting the rows in date/time format. I have also tried filter `feat_map = textFile.filter(lambda line: (len(line) > 0) and line != '\n').map(lambda line: line)`, but output is same.

Comment: Then why do both your attempts contain `'-------------------------------------------'`

Comment: Well, `-------------------------------------------`  has length > 0 and is not a single newline character.

Comment: Here is the link of file: [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRIG3kN-8Z9Nm1pZXR6MjVqS1U/view?usp=sharing] I am using. It does not contain any such line.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run the code on multiple workers (on multiple machines). The code worked on local machine (`MASTER=local[2]`) but failed with error on multiple machines. After many attempts I get error of file not found. So I placed the file on hdfs and attempt 2 code worked. Here is the full code:

```
txtFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://host:port/path/filename")
feat_map = txtFile.map(lambda line: line.split(','))\
                        .map(lambda word: (int(word[0]), int(word[1]), int(word[2])))\
                        .zipWithIndex().collectAsMap()
print(feat_map)
```